# i dont understand why we should include var result=false and result=true

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want users to input their numbers and see if they can get the lucky number correct but I don't understand why do we need to put `var result=false` and also
`result=true`

```js
var luckyNo;

function generateNumber() {
  luckyNo = 55;
}

function match(number) {
  var result = false; /* <== here */
  // compare number with the luckyNo
  // popup box to give hints to user too low or too high or bingo
  if (number > luckyNo)
    alert("Too high");
  else if (number < luckyNo)
    alert("Too low");
  else {
    alert("Bingo!");
    // update result if matched (bingo)
    result = true; /* <== here */
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: There are people who advocate that you should only have a return statement. And people who say that you should leave the function as early as possible with a return statement. It actually depends mostly on the used language and the exact use case.

Comment: there are multiple `alert` statements, then why just questioned about `result`?

Answer (score 0):

If they do not reach BINGO, you return false otherwise you return true.

That way you can do `if (match(someNumber)) { something() }` 
It is the a fairly standard way of returning a so-called `boolean` from a function

```js
function match(number) {
  var result = false;
  if (number > luckyNo) {
    alert("Too high");
  } else if (number < luckyNo) {
    alert("Too low");
  } else {
    alert("BINGO");
    result = true;
  }
  return result;
}
generateNumber();
if (match(prompt("enter number"))) {
  doSomethingWithTheWinner();
}

//or simpler

function match(number) {
  if (number > luckyNo) {
    alert("Too high")
    return false;
  }
  if (number < luckyNo) {
    alert("Too low");
    return false;
  }
  alert("BINGO");
  return true;
}
generateNumber();
if (match(prompt("enter number"))) {
  doSomethingWithTheWinner();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the ternary operator you can also do it without a formal `if`:

```
function match(n){
  var msg=n<luckyNo?'too low'
         :n>luckyNo?'too high'
         :'Bingo';
  console.log(msg);
  return n==luckyNo;
  // or, admittedly more obscure:
  // return msg=='Bingo';
}
```

Comment: But who would use such a construct? You need to read it multiple times to be sure that it actually does what you think it does. And using the content `msg` to "calculate" if `true` or `false` has to be returned also not a good design decision.

Comment: Yes, admittedly a more obscure way of doing it ... But still, a valid way. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It's just a little trick your program is doing. It's saying, "Set the result to false always, but if the user guesses the number right, then set the result to true"

That way is more efficient than saying something like "If the user guesses the number wrong, then set the result to false, else set the result to true."

Answer (score -1):

Actually you don't need result variable at all.

```js
function match(number) {
  if (number > luckyNo) {
    alert("Too high")
  }
  else if (number < luckyNo) {
    alert("Too low");
  }
  else {
    alert("Bingo!");
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: You still have a `result = true;` there.